# Reading file contents and POSTing in combination with KO mechanism

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I used this tutorial http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1006/edit-html-table-crud-knockoutjs-aspnet-webapi to create an editable table with KnockOutJS, without adding the ASP.NET stuff (only the KO part, server-side API is implemented in PHP). 
The tutorial works but I added a new feature which doesn't. Instead of outputting a text field I modified the instructions of the author to add a button instead of it in the table. What I am trying to achieve is to read the contents of a file image, store it in a variable and append in POST payload so as to be stored in a blob field in a database table.

Can someone please suggest an alternative way to achieve this or guide me to correct the existing one ? I'm quite a newbie to KnockOutJS and furthermore in Javascript.

```js
    var self = this;

    //S1:Boolean to check wheather the operation is for Edit and New Record
    var IsNewRecord = false;

    // filename to be converted into string for uploading
    var ImgFile = "";

    var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        //console.log("In handleFileSelect");
        if (files && file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
                ImgFile = readerEvt.target.result;
                //console.log("Printing the base64 ...");
                //console.log(readerEvt.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }
    };

    function executeCreateListener() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
           //console.log("In if");
            document.getElementById('filePicker').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false); // this sh** resolves to null due to KO dynamic nature
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }
    }

    self.ProductsApallou = ko.observableArray([]);
    
    loadProducts();

    //S2:Method to Load all Products by making call to WEB API GET method
    function loadProducts() {
        alert("Loading Data");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/goandwin/store_products.json?retrieve:Store_of_Product=1+Store_Product_id=999+Name=999+Subname=999+Imgname=999+Price=999+Product_Discount=999+Slogan=999+Origin=999+Description=999+Product_Code=999+Category_level_1_id=999+Product_Photo=999",
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(data) {
            self.ProductsApallou(data);
        }).fail(function(err) {});
        
        alert("Success");
    };

    //S3:The Product Object
    function Product(soproduct, spid, pname, subname, imgname, price, product_disc, slogan, origin, descript, product_code, cbid, pphoto) {
        return {
            Store_of_Product: ko.observable(soproduct),
            Store_Product_id: ko.observable(spid),
            Name: ko.observable(pname),
            Subname: ko.observable(subname),
            Imgname: ko.observable(imgname),
            Price: ko.observable(price),
            Product_Discount: ko.observable(product_disc),
            Slogan: ko.observable(slogan),
            Origin: ko.observable(origin),
            Description: ko.observable(descript),
            Product_Code: ko.observable(product_code),
            Category_level_1_id: ko.observable(cbid),
            Product_Photo: ko.observable(pphoto)
        }
    };

    //S4:The ViewModel where the Templates are initialized
    var ProdViewModel = {
        readonlyTemplate: ko.observable("readonlyTemplate"),
        editTemplate: ko.observable()
    };

    //S5:Method to decide the Current Template (readonlyTemplate or editTemplate)

    ProdViewModel.currentTemplate = function(tmpl) {
        return tmpl === this.editTemplate() ? 'editTemplate' : this.readonlyTemplate();
    }.bind(ProdViewModel);

    //S6:Method to create a new Blank entry When the Add New Record button is clicked
    ProdViewModel.addnewRecordApallou = function() {
        self.ProductsApallou.push(new Product(1, "auto", "default", "default", "default", 0, 0, "default", "default", "default", "default", 1, "default"));
        IsNewRecord = true;
    };
    
    //S7:Method to Save the Record (This is used for Edit and Add New Record)
    ProdViewModel.saveProduct = function(d) {
        var Prod = {};
        //console.log(d);
        Prod.Store_of_Product = d.Store_of_Product;
        Prod.Store_Product_id = d.Store_Product_id;
        Prod.Name = d.Name ? d.Name : null;
        Prod.Subname = d.Subname ? d.Subname : null;
        Prod.Imgname = d.Imgname ? d.Imgname : null;
        Prod.Price = d.Price ? d.Price : 0.0;
        Prod.Product_Discount = d.Product_Discount ? d.Product_Discount : 0;
        Prod.Slogan = d.Slogan ? d.Slogan : null;
        Prod.Origin = d.Origin ? d.Origin : null;
        Prod.Description = d.Description ? d.Description : null;
        Prod.Product_Code = d.Product_Code ? d.Product_Code : null;
        Prod.Category_level_1_id = d.Category_level_1_id ? d.Category_level_1_id : 1;

        //console.log("Printing imgfile ...");
        //console.log(ImgFile);
  
        // <---- HERE what I am trying to achieve, if possible
  if (ImgFile) {
            Prod.Product_Photo = ImgFile; //take the string produced after uploaded
        } else {
            Prod.Product_Photo = d.Product_Photo; //take the string as it was
        }
  // ---->
  
        //Edit the Record
        if (IsNewRecord === false) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1/goandwin/store_products/" + Prod.Store_Product_id,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                data: Prod
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert("Record Updated Successfully " + data.status);
                ProdViewModel.reset();
            }).fail(function(err) {
                alert("Error Occured, Please Reload the Page and Try Again " + err.status);
                ProdViewModel.reset();
            });
        }

        //The New Record
        if (IsNewRecord === true) {

            var tmp = Prod;
            delete tmp.Store_Product_id; //remove the PK which is auto

            IsNewRecord = false;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1/goandwin/store_products",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                data: tmp
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert("Record Added Successfully " + data.status);
                ProdViewModel.reset();
                loadProducts();
            }).fail(function(err) {
                alert("Error Occured, Please Reload the Page and Try Again " + err.status);
                ProdViewModel.reset();
            });
        }
    }

    //S8:Method to Delete the Record
    ProdViewModel.deleteProduct = function(d) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/goandwin/store_products/" + d.Store_Product_id
        }).done(function(data) {
            //console.log(d.Store_Product_id);
            alert("Record Deleted Successfully " + data.status);
            ProdViewModel.reset();
            loadProducts();
        }).fail(function(err) {
            alert("Error Occured, Please Reload the Page and Try Again " + err.status);
            ProdViewModel.reset();
        });
    }

    //S9:Method to Reset the template
    ProdViewModel.reset = function(t) {
        this.editTemplate("readonlyTemplate");
    };

    ko.applyBindings(ProdViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="Apallou" class="tab-pane fade in inactive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-exampleApallou">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Store_of_Product</th>
                    <th>Store_Product_id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Subname</th>
                    <th>Imgname</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Product_Discount</th>
                    <th>Slogan</th>
                    <th>Origin</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Product_Code</th>
                    <th>Category_level_1_id</th>
                    <th>Product_Photo</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: currentTemplate, foreach: ProductsApallou }"></tbody>
        </table><br><input type="button" value="Add New Record" data-bind="click: function () { ProdViewModel.addnewRecordApallou(); }" /><br></div>
  
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<script type="text/html" id="readonlyTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Store_of_Product"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Store_Product_id"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Subname"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Imgname"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Price"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Product_Discount"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Slogan"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Origin"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Product_Code"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Category_level_1_id"></span></td>
        <td><img width="60px" height="70px" data-bind="attr:{src: Product_Photo}" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type='button' value='Edit' data-bind='click: function () { ProdViewModel.editTemplate($data);}'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='button' value='delete' data-bind='click: function () { ProdViewModel.deleteProduct($data); }'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="editTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Store_of_Product' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Store_Product_id' disabled='disabled' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Name' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Subname' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Imgname' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Price' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Product_Discount' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Slogan' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Origin' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Description' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Product_Code' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' data-bind='value: $data.Category_level_1_id' /></td>
        <td>
            <div><label for="filePicker">Choose a file:</label><input type="file" id="filePicker"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click: ProdViewModel.saveProduct" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-bind="click: function () { ProdViewModel.reset(); }" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</script>
```

I know my explanation of what I'm trying to do is somehow vague, so feel free to ask questions to make things clear. My project lies [here](http://www.san-soft.com/sansoftcrm) if someone wishes to check it out (dpesios, test).

Comment: wow, that's a lot of code to debug, it will be **so** useful if you create a jsFiddle, or [create a snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/#how-do-i-make-a-stack-snippet) with the editing tools provided in the question to test it.

Comment: You are right and I apologize for this. I will do it asap.

Comment: No need to apologize, but your Ajax call is not working, CORS is not allowed in the snippet. I checked your page and noticed that you're not returning the calls as JSON, but as HTML. Apart from that, your image is always storing `default` in it, debug the model stored after saving, it seems to not be working as you expect.

Comment: Well, the project is still under heavy development in many aspects. Regarding the defaulting of the image, that is the problem I'm trying to solve by creating this post. "default" is a just a temporary value that I try to overwrite using "handleFileSelect" with a base64 image string.